# Buttons not working with localhost/xxxxx.html

Tags: html, button, localhost, href

I have written a code for my html website project. When I open the html file itself, it loads correctly on various browsers. However, when I try to access the same file via localhost/xxxxx.html, the buttons don't seem to work. Other images and links work fine. All the files are placed within the same folder.

I have used a `href` along with the `button` element.

Can someone please help me? The project is due tomorrow and I am not a technology/coding native.

TIA!

Comment: That's not enough information to help you

Comment: Please paste your code so we can take a look at it! Are the files you are trying to access in the same folder as the index?

Comment: I think Ale Plo here is hinting that you might be having a relative vs. absolute path problem. If you share your code, I'm sure you'll have your answer in no time.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all your code it's tough to know why it's not working in your localhost. But... within the `<button>` element it's not typical to add an href the same way you would with an `<a>`. You can do it but with an `onclick` event in javascript.
I would suggest doing an `<a href="xxx" class="button">Text</a>` and styling the .button class in your css.
Hopefully this helps and good luck on your project.

Answer (score 0):

The button element will not redirect you to the link you want because that's not what it is built for.

As you said, your link works fine, so you can use your link to navigate.

If you still want to use the button element, you can wrap it with the `<form action="the_link_you_want_to_navigate" method="GET">`. You can also use JavaScript code with a `click` event listener too.

But I think the best way to do this is by using the `<a>` tag and make it looks like a button using CSS properties.